# get input text value when checkbox selected in li jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to get only input value from li those checkbox is selected and send to the controller as key value pair means key as checkbox id and value as a input textbox value. There is multiple li inside ul.
 
I found something like a

```
$('li').find('input:checked, input[type=text]').map(function(i,el) {
        getInputVal=  el.type === 'checkbox' 
                ? el.value 
                :""; 
    });
```

But not working.

Following is the my html code structure.

```
<ul id="sortable">

<li id="row_39" class="img">
            <div class="checkbox"> 
                <input type="checkbox" value="Mzk=" class="set_left" name="remove_img[]" id="remove_img[]">
                <b><label class="set_center">1</label></b>
            </div> 
            <div class="img_main">
                <a rel="gallery" class="boxer" title="AA" href="/prod_images/prod_21_13905400722.jpg">
                    <img width="'200  height=" 136="" src="/prod_images/prod_21_13905400722.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="desc">
                <input type="text" value="AA" class="textbox" name="update_caption[]">
            </div>
    </li>
    <li id="row_43" class="img">
            <div class="checkbox"> 
                <input type="checkbox" value="NDM=" class="set_left" name="remove_img[]" id="remove_img[]">
                <b><label class="set_center">2</label></b>
            </div> 
            <div class="img_main">
                <a rel="gallery" class="boxer" title="AA" href="/prod_images/prod_21_13905400726.jpg">
                    <img width="'200  height=" 134="" src="/prod_images/prod_21_13905400726.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="desc">
                <input type="text" value="AA" class="textbox" name="update_caption[]">
            </div>
    </li>
          ..........
```

Please suggest me some answer.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
var params = {};
$('li input:checked').each(function (i, el) {
    params[this.id] = $(this).closest('li').find('input:text').val()
});
console.log(params)
```

Note: Your checkbox id is static so you will be overriding the same key in the object, you `li` elements has a dynamic part in its id, do you want to use that as the key for the params object

Comment: @BlackSheep looks like I messed it up - was working on another version using .has() then changed the logic but forgot to change the selector - the update should fix it I think(still the id of the checkbox issue remains)

Comment: I see, I was about to post an answer which would create an array of objects. As you had suggested a reasonable solution I didn't post it.

Comment: @arun yes i want to use key as a input type checkbox and value as input type text.

Comment: @nileshwani which key.... can you share a sample of generated html and the desired result

Comment: @nileshwani now what is the desired output

Comment: when i select three checkboxes then only last input value get inserted like  desired o/p is:- remove_img[]  "A"

Comment: @nileshwani http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c7gKL/1/ or `http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c7gKL/2/

Comment: @nileshwani it is because all the checkbox elements has the same id - `remove_img[]`